# Grafana: only 1 minute of data points visible for last 5 minutes

Tags: graphite, grafana

I cannot seem to determine why Grafana is only displaying data points for the past minute even though we have been collecting data for longer than that (couple days).

That is, switching to "5 minutes ago" only displays the last minute of data and seems to cut off with each refresh. **However**, selecting a specific time range displays all data points correctly.

[image]

For this data path, storage-schemas.conf is setup like so:

```
retentions = 1s:24h,15s:7d,1m:30d
```

From what I gather, that means that I should have 1-second precision data for the past 24 hours, 15-second data for the past 7 days, and 1-minute average for 30 days. Is this also a correct assumption and if not, could it be related to the grafana problem?

Comment: Did you change your retention settings recently? After restarting, they are only applied to newly created series. Try recreating the same graphics with new series. Also, the cutoff you see might be related to the `xFilesFactor` setting (see http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config-carbon.html#storage-aggregation-conf)

Comment: I did not, but I also cleared existing whisper files.

Comment: @dukebody, what should xFilesFactor setting be to display full graphs for "Last 5 minutes" and not just the last minute?

Comment: Are you using statsd? If so, check https://github.com/etsy/statsd/blob/master/docs/graphite.md

Comment: I am not using statsd, but I'll take a look at that guide!.